# Adding editor styles to the Astra theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin, wordpress-6

I'm using the Astra theme (with the Astra Pro plugin). I'm trying to enqueue some custom editor styles for some block patterns I have created. I tried this first: `add_theme_support('editor-styles');` but the moment I did--before even getting to `add_editor_style`--some unfortunate things happened, e.g. the text in a default paragraph block displayed much smaller. I was able to use the `add_editor_style()` function, and could then correct the problem with the small font size, but that means a lot of extra work to do to correct any other styles that inadvertently affected by the `add_theme_support('editor-styles)` function . Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Please note: I am running WP v6.0.1, Astra theme 3.9.0 (with a child theme), and Astra Pro v3.9.0. I'd be grateful for any suggestions or assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

````
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tg-pattern-styles',  get_theme_file_uri( '/tg-pattern-styles.css' ) );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'tg_block_styles' );```

It works for front and back end.
````